# how to control tabs current effect using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have html form which contains a tab menu the code is

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.:" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:400:&SESSION.:" class="current">Leave Eligibility</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:450:&SESSION.:" class="current2">Apply Leave</a></li>
    <li><a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:300:&SESSION.:" class="current3">Change Password</a></li>
    <li><a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:11:&SESSION.:" class="current4">Applied Leaves</a></li>
        <li><a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:25:&SESSION.:" class="current4">Holidays</a></li>
        <li><a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:445:&SESSION.:" class="current4">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the css of this html is

```
#menu{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: #111;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px #9c9c9c;
}

#menu li{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}

#menu a{
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0 25px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

#menu li:hover > a{
    color: #fafafa;
}

*html #menu li a:hover{ /* IE6 */
    color: #fafafa;
}

#menu li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
}

/* Sub-menu */

#menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    background: #444;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #111),color-stop(1, #444));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#menu ul li{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
}

#menu ul li:last-child{
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#menu ul a{
    padding: 10px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
}

*html #menu ul a{ /* IE6 */
    height: 10px;
    width: 150px;
}

*:first-child+html #menu ul a{ /* IE7 */
    height: 10px;
    width: 150px;
}

#menu ul a:hover{
        background: #0186ba;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#04acec), to(#0186ba));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
    background: linear-gradient(#04acec,  #0186ba);
}

#menu ul li:first-child a{
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: -8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #444;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after{
    border-bottom-color: #04acec;
}

#menu ul li:last-child a{
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

/* Clear floated elements */
#menu:after{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

* html #menu             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html #menu { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
ul#menu li a.active{
        color: #fafafa;
    }
```

So by default home tab is hovered when the page loaded.
When i will click leave eligibility tab the hover effect of home tab will be disabled and 
the leave eligibility tab will be hovered.
I want to use javascript/jquery to control it.
So anyone please tell me how to do it.

Comment: the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/Hn54A/) you provided us is unreachable.

Comment: i think now u can see the result check the link http://jsfiddle.net/Hn54A/

Comment: what environment you are using for develop the pages?

Comment: sorry for the last post. when i am trying this code in the link (http://jsfiddle.net/Hn54A/) it is showing me currect output.but when i try to open the link in another tab it is showing me the wrong output. thanks regards

Comment: i am using  notepad to write the code

Comment: can please try this link http://jsfiddle.net/Hn54A/1/

Comment: for every menu you using a different page?

Comment: yes for every menu i am using different page

Answer (score 0):

if you are using notepad then try with the code segments.

on your home page the design should be like this

```
    <li><a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.:" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:400:&SESSION.:" class="current">Leave Eligibility</a>

    </li>
```

On your Leave Eligibilty page

```
 <li><a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.:" class="current">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:400:&SESSION.:" class="active">Leave Eligibility</a>

    </li>
```

and so on for other pages.

i put it for your quick reference...

Try this

```
$("a").live('click', function() {
  $("a").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  return false;
});
```

Check the output here http://jsfiddle.net/Hn54A/3/

Comment: yes i can do this  and it will work.So can i use javascript to do it.if yes please tell me how regards

Comment: class active is my home tab.so i will remove all the class of others tabs or what.

Comment: @user1314585:check the fiddle i added in the answer

Comment: @user1314585: yes you can remove it